# Dictionaries and For Loops

Tags: python

say that the following is our code:

```
d = {"Happy":"Clam", "Sad":"Panda"}
for i in d:
    print(i)
```

now     `print(i`) will print out just the keys, but how could I change it so that it printed the values?

Comment: `print i,d[i]` is one easy way.

Comment: Thanks, but why does d[i] refer to the values?

Comment: That's just how dictionaries work in python.  `d[i]` is the value for key `i`.

Comment: The formula is dict[key] = value

Comment: @algebr `d[i]` refers to the value `i` in the dictionary. If you were looking for say the value of `"Happy"` you would do `d["Happy"]`. With a for loop you go through those keys using `i`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A Python [dict](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict) has a number of methods available for getting a list of the keys, values, or both.

To answer your question, you can use `d.values()` to get a list of the values only:

```
d = {"Happy":"Clam", "Sad":"Panda"}
for v in d.values():
   print(v)
```

Output:

```
Clam
Panda
```

The `items()` method is particularly useful, though, so should be mentioned.

```
d = {"Happy":"Clam", "Sad":"Panda"}
for k, v in d.items():
   print(k, v)
```

will print:

```
Happy Clam
Sad Panda
```

A warning about the ordering of items from the documentation:

> **CPython implementation detail:** Keys and values are listed in an
>   arbitrary order which is non-random, varies across Python
>   implementations, and depends on the dictionary’s history of insertions
>   and deletions.

Comment: If this is the answer you like most make sure to mark as answer.

Answer (score 2):

```
d = {"Happy":"Clam", "Sad":"Panda"}
for i in d:
    print(i, d[i]) # This will print the key, then the value
```

or

```
d = {"Happy":"Clam", "Sad":"Panda"}
for k,v in d.items(): # A method that lets you access the key and value
    print(k,v) # k being the key, v being the value
```

Answer (score 1):

```
d = {"Happy":"Clam", "Sad":"Panda"}
for i in d:
        print(i, d[i])
```

Gives me:

```
('Sad', 'Panda')
('Happy', 'Clam')
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple approach would to use a for each loop

```
for value in d.values:
    print(value)
```

You could also make a generator.  Generators are iterable sequences that you can stop and resume.

```
def generator(input):
    for value in input.values():
        yield value

gen = generator(d);
print(d.next()) // Clam

// Doing complex calculations
answer = 21 + 21

print(d.next()) // Panda
```

Another way is using the higher order function 'map'.

```
map( print, d.values() )

// You can also use generators ;)
map( print, gen )
```

Lastly, in python 3 dictionaries now support compression.  Dictionary compression is great for creating dictionaries, not so much for printing the content of each entry's value.  It's something worth googling, since everything in python is a dictionary.